# Better way to write this Python function because of If conditions

Tags: python, if-statement, python-requests

```
def do_request(url, token, json_data=None,
               mode="get", work_around_for_image_custom_list=False):

    """Uploads a file. """
    header_collection = {"X-Auth-Token": token}
    if json_data is not None:
        header_collection['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    try:
        if mode == "delete":
            # this looks ugly, but there is absolutely no way to
            # get requests to do DELETE when there is a blank JSON
            # included
            r = requests.delete(url, headers=header_collection, timeout=10)
        else:
            r = getattr(requests, mode)(url, data=json.dumps(json_data),
                                        headers=header_collection, timeout=10)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            #This looks ugly also, but has to be for a particular function that calls it
            if work_around_for_image_custom_list:
                return r
            else:
            http_info = (json.dumps(r.json(), indent=2), r.status_code)
        else:
            http_info = (r.text, r.status_code)
        return http_info
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print "Connection Error! Http status Code {}".format(r.status_code)
        sys.exit()
    except (requests.exceptions.RequestException,
            requests.exceptions.HTTPError):
        print "Ambiguous Error! Http status Code {}".format(r.status_code)
        sys.exit()
```

Using Python 2.7 and the requests module, I have this function that I call with several other functions to make api calls. However, I have to make an exception for one particular function and return the request object...if `work_around_for_image_custom_list` is True. This seems seems like a ugly hack/work around and I am wondering how I could re-write it to compensate if work_around_for_image_custom_list. For instance, would it be better to make this a class and have each function create a object to use it? If so, how would I over ride `if r.status_code == 200:`?

Comment: Why not just have a function as above except it always returns `r` and another function that uses the first function to generate your `http_info` result based on the `r` it gets from the first one. Then you call whichever function is relevant.

Comment: I thought about doing it, but then the the functions that call it will have repetitive code for json.dumps(r.json(), indent=2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the comment I made:

```
def do_raw_request(url, token, json_data=None, mode="get"):
    """Uploads a file. """
    header_collection = {"X-Auth-Token": token}
    if json_data is not None:
        header_collection['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    try:
        if mode == "delete":
            # this looks ugly, but there is absolutely no way to
            # get requests to do DELETE when there is a blank JSON
            # included
            r = requests.delete(url, headers=header_collection, timeout=10)
        else:
            r = getattr(requests, mode)(url, data=json.dumps(json_data),
                                        headers=header_collection, timeout=10)

        if r.status_code == 200:
                return r, r.status_code
        return r.text, r.status_code

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print "Connection Error! Http status Code {}".format(r.status_code)
        sys.exit()
    except (requests.exceptions.RequestException,
            requests.exceptions.HTTPError):
        print "Ambiguous Error! Http status Code {}".format(r.status_code)
        sys.exit()
```

Then:

```
def do_request(url, token, json_data=None, mode="get"):
    res, code = do_raw_request(url, token, json_data, mode)
    if code == 200:
       return (json.dumps(r.json(), indent=2), r.status_code)
    return res, code
```

and now you call either `do_raw_request` or `do_request` as appropriate.
Note that I changed the return so it always returns a tuple otherwise you would have to start checking types to know whether you have a status text or a response object.